# swift SceneKit object is empty

Tags: swift, scenekit

im trying to show a earth model on screen, loaded model from [here](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/free-blender-3d-model/1027149) (tried and other same models), but id didn't show on screen

```
[let scene = SCNScene(named: "tierra-1.obj")

if scene == nil {
    print("nuuuul")
    return
}
// 2: Add camera node
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
// 3: Place camera
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)

// 4: Set camera on scene
scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

// 5: Adding light to scene
let lightNode = SCNNode()
lightNode.light = SCNLight()
lightNode.light?.type = .omni
lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

// 6: Creating and adding ambien light to scene
let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
ambientLightNode.light?.type = .ambient
ambientLightNode.light?.color = UIColor.darkGray
scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

// If you don't want to fix manually the lights
sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

// Allow user to manipulate camera
sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true

// Show FPS logs and timming
sceneView.showsStatistics = true

// Set background color
sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

// Allow user translate image
sceneView.cameraControlConfiguration.allowsTranslation = false

// Set scene settings
sceneView.scene = scene][2]
```

but after loading I have empty screen ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmTzV.jpg)), how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied and ran your code using a custom obj, I got it loaded and in the viewport.

I loaded in an obj, using a node, and not trying to load the obj as the scene itself.

I noticed that your camera is at world space 0,0,0. that would most likely be inside the mesh, which would appear see through as materials are defaulted with backface culling on.

I assign the material to be blue, just to make it easier to spot incase the asset is very small. I would suggest selecting the asset in XCode, and you can see the bounding box size. This will help get a better idea for how far away you need to move the camera to get it to see the mesh.

```swift
import ModelIO
import SceneKit
import SceneKit.ModelIO
import PlaygroundSupport

let scene = SCNScene()
let sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:800, height:800))
// Set scene settings
sceneView.scene = scene

// 2: Add camera node
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
// 3: Place camera
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 10)

// 4: Set camera on scene
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

// Material
let blueMaterial = SCNMaterial()
blueMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue

// Accessing the Playground resource folder
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"randomAsset", ofType: "obj")
let asset = MDLAsset(url: URL(string: path!)!)
let object = asset.object(at: 0)
let objNode = SCNNode(mdlObject: object)
objNode.geometry?.materials = [blueMaterial]
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(objNode)

// Allow user to manipulate camera
sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true

// Show FPS logs and timming
//sceneView.showsStatistics = true

// Set background color
sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

// Allow user translate image
sceneView.cameraControlConfiguration.allowsTranslation = true

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(sceneView)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! can u explain how did you calculate the "z" ?

Comment: As you have an object that you are going to load, in XCode select the object and you should be able to get a view of the object which will also have some extra attribute data on the right hand side. In the right column there will be a bounding box. This is a box that the object fits into. so if you move your camera to a distance greater than the bounding box, you should be able to see the object. If your camera is inside the object(geometry) you will see nothing as the default materials applied to geometry are not double sided, so all backfaces get culled(appear invisible)

Comment: you can also call .boundingbox on the SCNNode, to get the size of the bounding box, and then use that to position your camera.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think SceneKit supporst loading an Obj as a scene. They currently only allow types that have the ability to export scene data eg.camera,lights. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenesource

If you want to load the obj file you will have to import it into your scene.
This post should help https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3979

Comment: SceneKit can import obj files through Model I/O (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlasset/1391813-canimportfileextension)